# Maven or Ant + Ivy

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, ant, ivy

I am about to start a Java project(Android One) and was wondering what would be the best Project Management Approach? Maven or Ant + Ivy

What are the strengths and weaknesses of each? I have taken a look online and like mavens simplicity, but am told that it is hard to do custom things with it when my project needs them.

I have used Ant in the past, but never with a dependency management tool like Ivy

Also, I will be using Eclipse, so ease of integration would also be a factor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as custom tasks can be developed for Ant, custom plugins can be written for Maven.  Additionally, you can always call Ant tasks from Maven if/as you need.

Especially recently, Maven integrates really well into Eclipse using [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) (formerly m2eclipse).

My opinion:  Go with Maven.